# Use multiple different domain for one facebook app

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, subdomain

I have the Facebook app that is running perfectly fine. I just launched the new company and i would like to use the same Facebook approved app that works for both companies. Is there anyone know how to manage the two different domains in the same app.
Note I already add the domains in the Valid OAuth Redirect URls but how we can add two separate logo in the same developer app account.

Hope you understand what I mean.

Wahab

Comment: You can not add two different logos for the same app. If you need different app logos for the different sites - then you have to use two different app ids to begin with.  The different app-scoped user ids you will then get, can be matched if you associated both apps with the same business - for details on that, see docs.

Comment: like @misorude said, you need 2 apps. check this out -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/

Comment: thanks it make sense @misorude